# FireBase getToken(/ forceRefresh / true) does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I got this code from firebase and can not run in Angular 2 CLI , it show  unreachable code . how can i replace this or make it works ;

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(/ forceRefresh / true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

Thank you every one .

Comment: Which part of the code is unreadable

Comment: (/ forceRefresh / true) - this part

Comment: /* forceRefresh */

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this issue is to check if the user exists first and then get the token id. `getToken()` has been deprecated. Try using [getIdToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#getIdToken)

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
});
```